# Update Google Cloud Function Runtime version

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've been assigned a task to update google cloud functions runtime to node 20(currently the runtime is node 14). After reading documentation it seems that I just need to update node in package.json and run `gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --runtime NODE_RUNTIME`. The issue is that one of the functions uses a lot(about 50) npm packages and I can't update each of them currently. I was wondering if there is another way to update runtime without updating node modules (create a docker) etc. Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remember this rule: Test and Verify before Deploying. Do that on your local system first.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime is not a simple configurable property of a deployed function.  You **must** redeploy the function in order to get a new runtime.  Deployment will build a whole new image for that function with the requested runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the information, so as I understand  I'll need to update npm packages to be compatible with node 20, and redeploy function in order to get node 20 runtime.